# Bash script to run a dotnet command line app getting ' as cli argument

Tags: bash, .net-core

I wrote a .net core command line app and I wanted to easily be able to run it from the command line on multiple platforms. For Windows I wrote a cmd file. For Linux and MacOs I wrote a bash script.

.net core apps compile to a DLL. To run them from the command line you enter:

`dotnet myApp.dll <my command line args>`

My bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet ./myApp.dll "$@"
rc=$?
exit $rc
```

When I run my app through the shell script I get the following error: `' is not recognized.`
But if I skip the shell script, and run the app directly as `dotnet myapp.dll` I get no error whether running on Windows or Linux.

I believe the error is being generated by the library I'm using for command line parsing, but I suspect the problem may be in my bash script.
This is the library that I'm using for Command line parsing.
https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

If I add `echo "$@"` to the top of the script, I see my command line argument echoed to the console.

Is there an error in my bash script?
Is there a better way to write this script?

There could be multiple command line arguments and I want to pass them all to my application as if I had run the app directly using the `dotnet` cli.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Try changing your script file to unix line endings.

Comment: holy crap, I think that fixed it.

Comment: if you put that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your script file to unix line endings `\n`.

Comment: for anyone who comes along later you can either use Notepad++ to do the conversion (Edit->EOL Conversion) or on Linux use dos2unix.